# Transfer/Migrate data from one jackrabbit repository (Magnolia repository) to another jackrabbit repository

Tags: jackrabbit, jcr, magnolia

Anyone knows how to transfer/migrate contents from one Magnolia CMS repository (Jackrabbit repository) to another custom jacrabbit repository used by our application?

Answer (score 3):

As suggested by the other poster, the XML import/export functionality allows you to copy content between repositories.

Unfortunately the XML import/export functionality does not cover migrating data like version histories or custom node types. To migrate such data, you can use the [backup/migrate feature](http://jackrabbit.apache.org/standalone-server.html#StandaloneServer-Backupandmigration) of the Jackrabbit standalone jar.

Answer (score 0):

According to the API you should be able to use the import/export methods on Session.

http://www.day.com/maven/jsr170/javadocs/jcr-2.0/javax/jcr/Session.html

Answer (score 0):

Seems like what you need is `RepositoryCopier` tools
https://jackrabbit.apache.org/api/1.6/org/apache/jackrabbit/core/RepositoryCopier.html

One may copy repository to repository easily via the API of it.